# Working copy locked by not displayed - SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I updated my SVN (to 1.8.0.24401) and AnkhSVN (to 2.5.12059.347). Since then I am not prompted who has locked working copy for file when acquiring lock for file.

[image]

Previously it was used to show user who locked the working copy, but it is not showing user in dialog now.
Can anyone suggest how can I make dialog to show username who locked working file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by implementation details in the Serf library, where
now a lock with limited information is reported.

there is a workaround in AnkhSVN. The fix is available in the `2.5.12266` release.